# Laravel insert var inside get function

Tags: php, laravel

Am i doing it wrong, i tried to insert a value inside a global function.

```php
$servz = $revz->service;
$amount = Config::get("prices.".$servz."[0]");
```

I expect it to be :
$amount = Config::get("prices.A1[0]");

Comment: I think you may want Config::get("prices.".$servz)[0];

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the helper to set and get, it uses array notation and is a little easier to follow.  So to set a timezone for example:

```
  config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

and to get, just:

```
$value = config('app.timezone');
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration) - pretty good explanation there.

Comment: This is inside a loop, i need to get specific config with the loop result. like timezone1, timezone2 and so on. like config('app.timezone'.$x)

Comment: Just use double quotes and you can place the variable right inside.  so: `config("app.timezone$x")` would give you timezone1 as you wish.